# Line containing a vector equation

Tags: differential-geometry

In Do Carmo 1.5.1d, it asks:

> Show that, for the parametrized curve $\alpha(s) = (a$ cos $\frac{s}{c}, a$ sin $\frac{s}{c}, b\frac{s}{c})$, the lines containing the normal $n(s)$ passing through the point $\alpha(s)$ are orthogonal to the z axis

I understand what the problem is asking, and I can see how to do it given the equations ($n \bullet e_3 = 0$ clearly), but what I don't see how to do is obtaining the equation of such a line.  How exactly do you get an equation for a line "containing a vector?"

At first, one is tempted to use $n(s) \bullet (x,y,z) +$ (constant depending on $\alpha$) = 0 or something, but I'm not sure how to keep the third term of $\alpha(s)$ out of the equation.

Comment: Is this a faithful reproduction of the problem?  I don't understand the phrase "lines passing containing."

Comment: @Muphrid Sorry, "passing" wasn't supposed to be there

Comment: All right.  And what is $\alpha(s)$?  Is it the curve you already described?

Comment: @Muphrid Yes, added to clarify.  There are constraints on the constants, but I'm looking to see how this is done in general instead of just in this case.

Comment: Google *"equation of line in space through one point in given direction"* to find something like [this](http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/space/line_space.html). Of course, one does not need to deal with such equations to solve this problem.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thanks, I was unable to find good search queries.

I don't doubt that there are alternative solutions, but I'm just starting out (and am struggling), so they aren't as readily apparent.

Comment: Can you show us your version of the expression for the normal $n(s)$ or any steps towards this? Even if you find a vector proportional to the normal, it is easy to show then that it is orthogonal to the $z$ axis.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin The normal in this case is $(-$cos $\frac{s}{c}$, $-$sin $\frac{s}{c}, 0)$.  Orthogonality with the $z$ axis is straightforward - at least if I'm looking at it right (dot product with $(0,0,k)$ is zero for $k \in \mathbb{R}$). I just had trouble with showing the lines intersected the $z$-axis, which was why I asked this question.  The equation for the line I obtained was $\frac{x - cos \frac{s}{c}}{cos \frac{s}{c}} = \frac{y - sin \frac{s}{c}}{sin \frac{s}{c}}$ and $z = b \frac{s}{c}$. Clearly the point $(0,0,b\frac{s}{c})$ is on this line, so it intersects the $z$-axis.

Comment: It is acceptable to answer your own question (not in the comments, but properly), so that we can refer to your answer, comment it and vote for this. Moreover, it is acceptable to accept your own answer )))

Comment: @YuriVyatkin I'll do so then - wrote that down mostly for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal in this case is $(−cos \frac{s}{c}, −sin \frac{s}{c},0)$. Orthogonality with the z axis is straightforward (dot product with $(0,0,k)$ is zero for $k \in \mathbb{R})$. 
The equation for the line, using Yuri Vyatkin's link in the comments, is $\frac{x−cos\frac{s}{c}}{cos\frac{s}{c}}=\frac{y−sin\frac{s}{c}}{sin\frac{s}{c}}$ with $z=b\frac{s}{c}$ (a constant). Clearly the point $(0,0,b\frac{s}{c})$ is on this line, so it intersects the z-axis and both conditions have been satisfied.